# Setting up IPv6 environment using OSX 10.11 Beta 5 (El Capitan)

Tags: ios, macos, ipv6, osx-elcapitan

I'm having difficulty setting up an IPv6 environment using El Capitan on my Mid 2010 MacBook Pro.

I've followed the instructions presented on Apple's Developer site, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html, as well as a few instructions I've stumbled across on other websites, such as https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4971

I've gotten to the point where my other iOS devices have been able to connect to the IPv6 network hosted by the El Capitan machine, and these iOS devices can also access the Internet. Unfortunately, according to various websites that check IPv6 connectivity, these iOS devices are not actually using an IPv6 address.

In addition (not sure if this is important), when setting up my Internet Sharing options, the IPv6 checkbox is labeled **Create IPv6 Only Network** as opposed to **Create NAT64 Network**, which I commonly see on the tutorial websites I've seen. I doubt this is much of an issue, but just putting it out there.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your development setup. The Apple setup uses NAT64 so your internal IPv6 traffic is converted to external IPv4 traffic. That is why those IPv6 testing sites don't see IPv6: it has already been converted to IPv4.

Apple changed the label of the checkbox at some point between the beta and final releases but it's still the same function.